# How can i retrieve a distinct list in Linq?

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I Want My result like this

```
McLaren Cup
       The Regis Brunch
                  21st Jan 2017
                  24st Jan 2017
                  26st Jan 2017
       General Entry
       General Parking
        Picnic Parking
                  21st Jan 2017
                  24st Jan 2017
                  26st Jan 2017
```

For this i did LINQ query , But am getting exception as follows
*Additional information: The 'Distinct' operation cannot be applied to the collection ResultType of the specified argument.*

```
  var Ticketdata = (from Tevent in context.TicketEventsMaster
  where Tevent.IsActive == true && Tevent.IsVisible == true
  select new
  {
    EventID = Tevent.TicketEventID,
    eventName = Tevent.TicketEventName,
    EventCategories = (from TEM in context.TicketCategoriesMaster
       join TED in context.TicketEventDates on TEM.CategoryID equals TED.TCategoryID
       where TED.IsActive == true && TED.IsVisible == true && TED.TEventID == Tevent.TicketEventID
       //orderby TED.DisplayOrder
       select new
      {
          CategoryID = TED.TCategoryID,
          CategoryName = TEM.CategoryName,
          EventDates = (from tDate in context.TicketEventDates
            where
              tDate.IsActive == true && tDate.IsVisible == true
              && tDate.TEventID == Tevent.TicketEventID
              && tDate.TCategoryID == TEM.CategoryID
            orderby tDate.TEventDate
            select new
            {
              DateID = TED.ID,
              Dates = TED.TEventDate != null ? TED.TEventDate.ToString() : string.Empty,
              Times = TED.TEventTime != null ? TED.TEventTime.ToString() : string.Empty,
            }).ToList()
      }).Distinct().ToList()

  }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is lots of ways to get Distinct data.
you can use "DistinctBy" with deisred properties or you can use

```
 var result = table.GroupBy(test => test.id)
                   .Select(grp => grp.First())
                   .ToList();
```